# MySQL - Group by Parent/Child but order by time

Tags: mysql

I have a 'comment' system that allows for parent comments and also replies.

The following query groups the comments as follows

```
| Parent Comment Newest
-- Reply
-- Reply
| Parent Comment Oldest

SELECT *
FROM comments c
WHERE c.thred = 50
GROUP BY c.id  
   ORDER BY 
 IF(parent_id IS NULL, c.id, parent_id) DESC, 
 parent_id IS NOT NULL, 
 c.id ASC
```

However I want to modify this query to also take into consideration TIME.

I would like the PARENT comments to be sorted by 'last replied time' - so that the comments with the most recent activity are at the top.\

I can modify the code to allow for a **'last_reply'** column on the parent post to facilitate that if it makes the query easier - however I am at a loss to how to allow 'time' to factor into this query above.

An example of a system that does this would be Yammer. Posts are sorted by Newest posted but also old posts are pushed back to the top if there have been recent responses/replies.

Comment: I do not think you fully understand the use of group by because you do not try to summarise anything in your query, making the group by completely superfluous.

Comment: @Shadow i understand what you say, but wouldn't that be wrong tu asume also? maybe c.id is not unique which would be weird/kindofwrong to name it that way then but still we don't know if its a composed pk... or maybe he doesn't have primary keys at all

Comment: @Erubiel OK, let's assume c.id is not unique. Then vat will be the value of the other columns if you neither group on them, nor are summarised?

Comment: @Shadow... OK, but... maybe he summarized his select part of the query as *, otherwise, the question would be how to get rid of Error Code: 1055 hahaha

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The reason the group by is there is I removed a number of left join queries which would have duplicated rows